# Travis CI build errors Windows, Ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

I have actually 3 errors in Travis CI:
Here are the logs:

1:

```
Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
Installing erubis 2.7.0
An error occurred while installing rack (2.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rack -v '2.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
The command "eval bundle install --jobs=3 --retry=3 --deployment" failed. Retrying, 2 of 3.
```

*I installed `gem install rack -v '2.0.1' but I did not help.*
*Also I changed my travis.yml file so it is*

```
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
```

instead of:

```
rvm:
  - 2.2
```

2:

```
Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
Installing websocket-driver 0.6.4
An error occurred while installing mime-types-data (3.2016.0521), and Bundler
cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0521'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

*I installed `mime-types-data -v '3.2016.0521' but I did not help.*

3:

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Requested binary installation but no rubies are available to download, consider skipping --binary flag.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm rbx-2 do rvm gemset create ' first, or append '--create'.
The command "rvm use rbx-2 --install --binary --fuzzy" failed and exited with 2 during .
```

My travis.yml:

```
language: ruby
rvm:
  - 2.2.2
  - jruby
  - rbx-2
before_install:  
- gem update
- gem --version
before_script:
  - psql -c 'create database listapp_test;' -U postgres
addons:
  postgresql: '9.3'
```

I tried to update racks but I didn't help.
Ruby ver: ruby 2.2.4.p230
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have any logs about the actual error that occured?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are installing gem in places that Bundler cannot find it. It is much easier if you post build log URL that shows the problems you are having.

Note that Travis CI cannot support Rubinius on Precise any longer (issue #3 above) due to https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/3717. Try using Trusty instead.